# BAD IRI warning when running jena fuseki-server

Tags: command-prompt, jena, fuseki

I run jena fuseki on command promt using command `fuseki-server --update`. It says running but shows this warning:

[image]

I was wondering if maybe this is what is causing my endpoint to give me an error. I was using the endpoint "http://localhost:3030/diseaseDatav1/query".

Answer (score 0):

Use forward slashes in the file name.  `\` is in the "unwise" class of characters in the RFC that defines URIs.

`file:///c:/...`

3 `///` at the start.

It is a warning, not an error. The next line shows it gets fixed up.